# Corona Plugin from iOS static library (.a)

Tags: ios, lua, coronasdk

I'm new to CoronaSDK. I'm trying to make a plugin from my iOS static library (.a) which will be used in CoronaSDK (in a .lua file). Can you guide me through it? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm in the process of making it. I will let you know how it goes and how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to upgrade to Corona Enterprise (http://www.coronalabs.com/products/enterprise/) to be able to link in native libraries.

Comment: I will upgrade to Corona Enterprise. I want to make a Corona approved plugin from my own iOS static library. What's the next step? Can you guide me through? Thank you.